# Can i use same package name in two different appstore?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, app-store, amazon-appstore

Hope you are doing well, i want to know that can i use same package name two different appstore. For an example i want to upload my application in amazon appstore and google appstore. So can i use same package name or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using same package name. User might install from store 1, then install from store 2 without prior uninstalling. User now has version from store 2, but each store "thinks" that app is installed from it. So when you release newer version on store 1, it is pushed to user and he ends up with version from store 1, instead of store 2.
I assume there might be other conflicting scenarios.

Comment: That's is why you should sign the apk with different certificate per app store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure you can use same package for two different app store.

Comment: thanks for your help khurram. khurram is it possible that can you tell me how i can add interstitial Ad